# Jar files for spring-hibernate integration

Tags: spring, hibernate, jar

I'm working on Spring Hibernate Integration program as Ant with MySQL but I'm stuck with which jar files to add and at which location

I'm using `org.springworks.orm.hibernate.*`. Which specific jar file needs to be added?

Comment: I strongly suggest leaving ant behind and move on to Gradle or Maven. (Or at least add Ivy to manage your dependencies). In these times don't try to hunt down all the needed dependencies it is way to cumbersome and time consuming.

Comment: Did you try searching this on google?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the jar from [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-hibernate3).

But as suggest by M. Deinum, you should try upgrading to Maven or Gradle.